# Running an animation on a CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How does one run an animation or a series of pngs(e.g. 4 pngs) on a CCSprite?

Constantly make the CCSprites image be this animation series?

Also, how does one rotate a CCSprite's orientation? e.g. 45 degrees rotation to the left or right

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you want to update the sprite's source every so often according to a timer.

For rotating, check out this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/692/rotating-turrets